# Nagios agent not running

Tags: nrpe

Nagios is collecting stats from my RHEL server. I do not see that the nrpe agent nor snmp is running. How is this working?

Comment: Check the nagios host configuration for a start

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.